# Decreasing timer interval in WP7 Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, timer, dispatchertimer

I'm using `DispatcherTimer` in WP7 Silverlight to apply a simple translation animation on the menu.

Now, if I decrease the step length, the translation looks smooth, but slow. If I increase the step length, the translation looks fast, but not smooth.

The solution is to keep the step length small and decreasing the interval. But the problem is that the emulator makes the same number of steps for intervals equal 10 ms or less.

```
introTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
```

same as:

```
introTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
```

So is there a way/alternative/solution to make something happen repeatedly each very small amount of time?

Comment: Have you considered using a Storyboard for the animation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Actually, I haven't. But if it will solve my problem, I'll learn it.

Comment: It will, and it will be way more efficient (simple storyboards, if correctly written, can be hardware accelerated: http://www.japf.fr/2012/03/wp7-perf-tip-translate-transforms/ ).

Comment: Very nice, I will use it in my games.